# Neo4j multiple neo4j instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, neo4j

What is the best way to run 2 `neo4j` instances (with separate DBs)? I currently use Docker and having two instances on different ports seems to be working while only one instance is running, however when both - I can't get connection of either.

Comment: Please add what you have done so far and the issues you are facing when starting two instances at the same time.

Comment: @Raj I use docker-compose for the setup and have 2 instances declared there - `neo4j` and `neo4j-test` (with ports to -"7474:7474"/-"7687:7687" and  -"7475:7474"/-"7688:7687" respectively). When I run `docker-compose up -d neo4j neo4j-test` they both get started and I can verify it in browser ports however while I run tests using one of them, it gets killed (connectin can't be established) and second is alive and vise versa.

Comment: Can you check what's the errors in the log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start two Neo4j instances without any issues with or without docker.

**Without Docker**:

Change the Neo4j ports for http, https and bolt connections in `neo4j.conf` for one of the instance so that both starts on different ports.

**With Docker**:

You don't have to change neo4j config. 
You can give port mapping in docker run command with `-p` like:

```
docker run -d --rm --name neo4j-prod -p 11001:7474 -p 11002:7687 neo1
```

And for second instance use **7474 & 7687 instead of 11001&11002 resp**.  In this case you don't have to mention it in command.